# C++ with wxWidgets, Unicode vs. ASCII, what's the difference?

Tags: c++, unicode, ascii, wxwidgets

I have a Code::Blocks 10.05 rev 0 and gcc 4.5.2 Linux/unicode 64bit and
WxWidgets version 2.8.12.0-0
I have a simple problem:

```
#define _TT(x) wxT(x)
string file_procstatus;
file_procstatus.assign("/PATH/TO/FILE");
printf("%s",file_procstatus.c_str());
wxLogVerbose(_TT("%s"),file_procstatus.c_str());
```

Printf outputs "/PATH/TO/FILE" normally while wxLogVerbose turns into crap. When I want to change std::string to wxString I have to do following:

```
wxString buf;
buf = wxString::From8BitData(file_procstatus.c_str());
```

Somebody has an idea what might be wrong, why do I need to change from 8bit data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is to do with how the character data is stored in memory. Using the "string" you produce a string of type `char` using the ASCII character set whereas I would assume that the `_TT` macro expands to L"string" which create a string of type `wchar_t` using a Unicode character set (UTF-32 on Linux I believe).

the `printf` function is expecting a `char` string whereas `wxLogVerbose` I assume is expecting a `wchar_t` string. This is where the need for conversion comes from. ASCII used one byte per character (8 bit data) but `wchar_t` strings use multiple bytes per character so the problem is down to the character encoding.

If you don't want to have to call this conversion function then do something like the following:

```
wstring file_procstatus = wxT("/PATH/TO/FILE");
wxLogVerbose(_TT("%s"),file_procstatus.c_str());
```

Comment: Using wsString insted of std:string might be a solution, but then there comes problem when using OS functions (and STL functions too) that i need to convert everything.. And using always _TT (the alias for wxT) is pretty irritating. So i probably have to stick with converting std::string to wxString. :)

Comment: @ptrl4me: I think wxString should be OK with STL functions, and it seems to me `std::string` isn't any more convenient with OS functions.

Answer (score 0):

The following article gives best explanation about differences in Unicode and ASCII character set, how they are stored in memory and how string functions work with them.

http://allaboutcharactersets.blogspot.in/

Comment: What more does this article say than other answers to this question?